# Alternative to set_level_values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series of the form

```
  groupid     period    
        1    2011-02     5
        1    2011-03     6
        1    2011-04     7
        1    2011-05     8
```

Where I would like to shift the period by one period backwards. I can create the new index using

```
df.index.get_level_values('period').shift(-1)
```

but then I don't know how to force them back in. `set_level_values()` does not exist. How do I overwrite my second level of the MultiIndex?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html):

```
print (df.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[[1], [2011-02, 2011-03, 2011-04, 2011-05]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3]],
           names=['groupid', 'period'])

print (df.index.get_level_values('period').shift(-1))
PeriodIndex(['2011-01', '2011-02', '2011-03', '2011-04'], 
            dtype='period[M]', name='period', freq='M')

df.index.set_levels([df.index.get_level_values('groupid'), 
                     df.index.get_level_values('period').shift(-1)], inplace=True)
print (df)
groupid  period 
1        2011-01    5
         2011-02    6
         2011-03    7
         2011-04    8
Name: val, dtype: int64
```